# How to set a property in Powershell on an instance of a class that implements IDictionary and ICollection

Tags: c#, sqlite, powershell

I'm trying to work with the `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` class in the ADO.NET SQLite data provider library found [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). The class definition has a property called DataSource.

```
public sealed class SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder : DbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    public SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
    public SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder(string connectionString);

    public string DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

which I'm trying to set in my powershell script, viz:

```
$csb = new-object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder 
$csb.DataSource = "C:\data\mydb.db";
```

The problem I'm having is that `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` inherits from `DbConnectionStringBuilder` which implements the following interfaces

```
public class DbConnectionStringBuilder : IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, ....
```

Because the class implements these interfaces Powershell is NOT setting the property DataSource on the class but is treating `$csb` as a hash table and adding a key value pair to it i.e. `key="DataSource", value="C:\data\mydb.db"`. Needless to say this is not what I want. So what do I do now ? How to force Powershell set the property and not treat $csb to be a hash table? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to set this when you are creating the object it is possible using the `Property` parameter of `New-Object`:

```
$csb = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder -Property @{ DataSource = "C:\data\mydb.db" }
```

However if you are trying to set the property at some later time, the only way I have found is somewhat clumsy, using the .NET Reflection API:

```
$csb.GetType().GetProperty("DataSource").SetValue($csb, "C:\data\mydb.db")
```

Comment: Reflection isn't necessary - method syntax works - $csb.set_DataSource("C:\data\mydb.db")